# Finding eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &2 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0\\ 
2 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$

I found its eigenvalues: $\lambda_{1}=2, \lambda_{2}=2, \lambda_{3}=-2$.

With eigenvalue $2$, $A-\lambda I = \begin{bmatrix}
-2 & 0 &2 \\ 
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
2 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$, and I try to find the eigenvector $x$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &0  &2 \\ 
 0& 0 &0 \\ 
 2& 0 &-2 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 x \\ 
 y \\ 
 z 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ 
0  \\ 
0  
\end{bmatrix}$

Since two of the eigenvalues are $2$, I should find $2$ corresponding eigenvectors. I came up with $\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\ 
 0 \\ 
 0   
\end{bmatrix}$ (can eigenvectors be the zero vector?), $\begin{bmatrix}
1   \\ 
1 \\ 
1   
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
1   \\ 
 0 \\ 
 1   
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0   \\ 
 1 \\ 
 0   
\end{bmatrix}$, my question is how do know which two are the correct eigenvectors, or are all of them valid eigenvectors? Did I miss another possible eigenvector?

As for $\lambda_{3}=-2$, $\begin{bmatrix}
2 &0  &2 \\ 
 0& 4 &0 \\ 
 2& 0 &2 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 x \\ 
 y \\ 
 z 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ 
0  \\ 
0  
\end{bmatrix}$, possible eigenvector is just $\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\ 
0  \\ 
-1  
\end{bmatrix}$, which is a lot more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that eigenvector cannot be zero vector by its definition. Actually number of eigenvectors for a eigenvalue can be infinite but they form a linear space. So in your example, $\lambda=2$ has eigen space of dimension 2, so you can at most find 2 eigenvectors which are linear independent (Any other may produce dependence with previous ones).

Comment: So would the 2 eigenvectors be (1,0,1) and (0,1,0)? Since those two are linearly independent. And (1,1,1) is a linear combination of (1,0,1) and (0,1,0).

Comment: @Adrian Yes, they are.

Comment: Technically, pick any two of the three eigenvectors you listed.  The third is linear dependent on the first two.